# Win 11 - MySQL command not found in integrated VSCode CLIs but found in regular CLI

Tags: mysql, windows, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

I just installed MySQL into my system (server only).

When I run the command "mysql -V" on any CLI in VSCode (git bash, powershell, cmd), the command is not found. I usually use the integrated bash CLI. It's had no issue recognizing node, heroku, git commands.

When I run the CLIs in a separate window, they no problem recognizing the mysql command. What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

OS: Win 11 Pro

VSCode Ver: 1.81.1

MySQL Ver: 8.0.34

[Screenshot of Error and VSCode settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQmEf.png)

I tried restarting VSCode, restarting my system and adding a few lines to the settings.json file according to some older threads.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, restarting my computer a third time ended up working. I have no idea why it took three, but if anyone has any insight, please let me know!

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).